# Microsoft.Speech.Recognation and System.Speech.Recognation PlataformNotSupportedException

Tags: c#

Estou tendo um problema com  `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition`
e também com a `System.Speech.Recognation;`

Bom, eu consegui rodar a aplicação para suportar a língua inglesa, que no caso é padrão no meu SO, que é Windows 8.1 (x64), meu SO tá em Inglês.

É o seguinte, a aplicação que eu quero é que ele reconheça sons em português, mas para isso tive instalar esses 4 elementos no meu SO:

- Microsoft Speech Platform SDK,
- MSSpeech_SR_en-US_TELE,
- SpeechPlatformRuntime MSSpeech_TTS_en-BR_Heloisa,

Que vi em um tutorial no youtube, bom então eu tentei executar  usando a `Microsoft.Speech.Recognation` deu esse erro:

> Speech Recognition is not available on this system. SAPI and Speech
>   Recognition engines cannot be found.

Então eu tentei usar essa `System.Speech.Recognation` e passei na instancia da classe `Recognation` a Cultura pra português Brasil.

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine recEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-Br"));
```

Mas deu esse outro erro :

> No recognizer installed.

Eu não sei se tem haver com o Reconhecimento de Fala do windows, pois em computadores que são instalados em português têm 3 Idiomas no reconhecimento de voz, lá no Painel de Controle.

Bom, tipo eu queria que pelo menos uma delas funcionasse.

Segue um pouco código abaixo:

```
private void btnEnable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        btnDisable.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnDisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        recEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        btnDisable.Enabled = false;

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add(new string[] { "carro", "print my name"  , "joab" , "maria"});
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar gramar = new Grammar(gBuilder);

        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(gramar);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized; 


    }

    private void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Result.Text) { 

            case "carro":
                MessageBox.Show("Hello Jhon how are you ?");
                break;
            case "print my name":
                richTextBox1.Text += "Johon";
                break;
            case "joab":
                MessageBox.Show("Acertou Joab");
                break;
            case "maria":
                MessageBox.Show("Acertou Maria");
                break;





        }
    }
```

Lembrando que isso pega em inglês.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Visual Studio, acesse o *Configuration Manager*:

[image: Configuration Manager]

Crie uma nova plataforma:

[image: New Platform]

Especifique **x86** na plataforma. O *speech recognition* ainda não é homologado para x64.

[image: x86]

Comment: Funcionou ! (y)