# Reconhecimento de voz não funciona

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Recentemente formatei meu notebook e tive que reinstalar tudo, só que agora meu projeto de TCC está com erro que no caso antes não tinha.

Nesse trecho de código:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

O Erro que aparece:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
>
> Additional information: Nenhum reconhecedor da identificação necessária encontrado.

Aqui e o print da linguagem instalada....
[image: Aqui e o print da linguagem instalada]

Comment: pergunta simples para outra linguagem ele funciona?

Comment: Não compreendi sua pergunta...

Comment: se você colocar "en-US" seu programa compila sem erros ?

Comment: Não funciona, já tentei :/

Comment: é claro eu presumo que você tenha instalado o SpeechPlatformRuntime e as linguagens que você queira como suporte ....

Comment: Sim, editei ali e coloquei o print

Comment: O sistema operacional é o mesmo ou você alterou?

Comment: é o mesmo, senão me engano só troquei a versão dele, mas ambos é Windows 10

Comment: pq vc tem versão 64bits e 32bits instalado? será que isso não está gerando algum conflito !?

Comment: Posso tentar deixar uma só, é que no desespero instalei todos os possiveis. E a banca final do tcc esta chegando, e preciso concertar isso logo

Comment: deixei uma versao, mas o erro ainda persiste

Comment: Será que [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68686/20615) lhe ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há algumas soluções que resolvem este problema. Dentre as mais usadas:

1 - Verifique a versão do .NET Framework que está a usar e veja na documentação da DLL se suporta a mesma.

2 - Adicione uma referência (Via DLL) ao framework da ferramenta que deseja usar.

Caso nenhuma dê certo, verifique a documentação do framework.

Answer (score 1):

Não posso afirmar com exatidão como resolver o problema, mas o erro ocorre porque falta algum componente, no caso o que faz o reconhecimento em português, que claramente não vem por padrão no Windows. Veja o que precisa instalar.

Sempre que encontrar um erro, consulte a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0#System_Speech_Recognition_SpeechRecognitionEngine__ctor_System_Globalization_CultureInfo_) para entender melhor o que ocorre.